# Using php RTRIM function inside while loop constructing a table

Tags: php

I am building a form on a page where I'm supplying the DB values for those fields, and the end result is to allowing the "member user" to then update accordingly.

I am having difficulty trimming off the  trailing '/'. I am attempting to use RTRIM().

Query to grab my data:

```
`$m_q = "SELECT * FROM members where memid='$m_memid'";`
`$b_result = mysql_query($m_q);`
```

Code to loop through an build my table w/ prefilled data:

`while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($b_result)) {`
                `$m_userinfo .= "<tr class=\"logreg\">\r\n<td><b>First Name</b></td>";`
                `$m_userinfo .= "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\" value={$row['RTRIM(firstname)']}/></td></tr>"; .........`

The problem I'm having is nothing gets trimmed. When swapping the syntax around to:

`{$row[rtrim('firstname')]}` I see no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this outside the array indexing, or PHP will interpret it as the array index itself (the whole string 'rtrim(firstname)' in the first case, for example):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($b_result)) 
{ 
 $trimmed = rtrim($row['firstname'],'/');
 $m_userinfo .= "<tr class=\"logreg\">\r\n<td><b>First Name</b></td>"; 
 $m_userinfo .= "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\" value=\"{$trimmed}\"/></td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: or simply `$trimmed = rtrim($row['firstname'], "/");`

Comment: @diEcho Thanks, I skipped the part where he defined the character he wanted to trim... :/ . Corrected my answer

Comment: Why 'value=\"{$trimmed}\"' and not just 'value=\"$trimmed"'?

Comment: Thanks again!  That was exactly what i was looking for. I didn't gather that from the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Better way to trim during retrieve from Databse. try this

```
"SELECT TRIM(TRAILING  '/' FROM  `columname` ) AS fname, other columns FROM tableName"
```

Reference:

[`TRIM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

Comment: You know what, this is the right answer. Better to do this in the database than in PHP, no? +1

Answer (score 0):

```
value={rtrim($row['firstname'], '/')}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be simpler to use single quoted strings and dot concatenation. You can put your expression between the dots where ". $trimmed ." is if you want. I like to simplify the variables before doing string-work, myself

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($b_result)) 
{
 $trimmed = rtrim($row['firstname'],'/');
 $m_userinfo .= '<tr class="logreg">' . "\r\n" . '<td><b>First Name</b></td>'; 
 $m_userinfo .= '<td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="' . $trimmed . '"/></td></tr>';
}
?>
```

Sometimes I might do this. (Ever hear of heredoc?):

```
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($b_result)) 
    {

     $trimmed = rtrim($row['firstname'],'/');
     $m_userinfo .= <<<EOT
<tr class="logreg">
<td><b>First Name</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="$trimmed"/></td></tr>
EOT;
    }
// Read the manual about Heredoc if you don't know about it.
    ?>
```